# How do I convert Unix Line Termination to Windows?

Tags: linux, unix, notepad++, notepad, gedit

I am using Gedit and I save my script outputs as .txt so I could open it on Windows using Notepad but the problem is that Gedit does not use the same line termination as Notepad in Windows. I tried doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

but it does not yield any effect on my text files. I also cannot do the process where you save the file with the **Windows** option for the Line Ending because the text files are auto generated.

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you so much!

Additional detail: I have installed Notepad++ using WINE but I cannot make Notepad++ as the default program because it is installed using WINE.

Comment: Installing `dos2unix` is not enough, you should then execute it, passing paths to your files as arguments...

Comment: This question should go to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install unix2dos :

sudo apt-get install unix2dos

And then convert your saved files in linux:

unix2dos text.txt

Comment: What if my text files are outputs of scripts that run using the crontab, how do I make sure these texts will be automatically converted to my desired format (Windows Line Ending)?

Comment: Simply add the call to unix2dos at the end of your script.

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute dos2unix, not just install it.
try this...

```
unix2dos unixinput.txt winoutput.txt
```

and here is the awk way...

```
awk 'sub("$", "\r")' unixinput.txt > winoutput.txt
```

Comment: That has to be: dos2unix -n unixinput winoutput.txt
The default mode is in-place substitution.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use `fromdos` / `todos` commands .. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fromdos.1.html